# Separate drupal view filters from the results

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-search

I implemented a search index using Drupal Search API, and then created a view using that search index. In my view I added filters on searchable fields. My search is working very well.

However, my clients want to have the search filter controls in the sidebar and the search results in the main content region. But my filter controls and results are part of a single view. It is possible to separate them?

**Drupal version : 7.26**

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming when you talk about a 'view' you mean you are using the [views module](https://drupal.org/project/views).

If this is the case when you edit the view under the advanced section there is an option called "Exposed form in block" - it does exactly what is says on the tin.